# Catching SIGTERM in C with more processes

Tags: c, signals, fork, sigterm

I need that my program terminate properly all of its processes by catching SIGTERM signal, but even a CTRL+C (that is SIGINT i think). How can I modify it to make it works?
I tried to post only the code necessary to don't create confusion as the program works and I only have to add this signal management.

```
include <signal.h>
int nproc = 10;
int listaPID[10];
int forkValue;

int main (void){  
    signal(SIGTERM,signalHandler);
    //...
    createSM();
    for(int i=0; i<nproc; i++){ 
        forkValue = fork();       
        if(forkValue == 0)
            break;
        listaPid[i] = forkValue;    
    }

    if (forkValue==0){
        //child's tasks
        removeSM();
        exit(0);
    }
    //parent's tasks
    deleteSM(); 
    exit(0);
}

void signalHandler(int sig){ 
    //if parent, kill all of its childs + remove and delete shared memory + exit
    if (forkValue>0){
        for(int i=0;i<nproc;i++)
            kill((listaPid[i]),SIGTERM);
        deleteSM();
        exit(0);
    }
    //if son, remove shared memory + exit
    else {
        removeSM();
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ctrl-C triggers a `SIGINT` not a `SIGTERM`.

Comment: "*Is it correct*" As the code you show is incomplete, it is impossible to say if it is correct or not.

Comment: Actually, What is the question?

Comment: At least please tell us how and where  `forkValue` is defined and set.

Comment: No that's not correct. The `exit(3)` function is not signal-safe. An the signal() function works differently based on the os & libc type & version, the options used to compile the code and the phase of the moon, so it's completely unpredictable what that will do.

Comment: I'm sorry but I tried to put less code possible to dont make you waste time, anyway i just edited it.

Comment: "*can I modify it to make it work*" this might imply that currently it is not behaving as you expect. So tell is how it is behaving.

Comment: a parent should 'always' call `wait()` or `waitpid()` on its' child/children before exiting.  Not waiting for the child(ren) to exit results in 'zombie' processes which require a re-boot to eliminate.   Note, however, that modern OSs now attach the orphaned child to the 'init' process which stops the process from becoming a 'zombie'

Answer (score 1):

`^C` generates a `SIGINTR`, so you have to install handlers for that signal also.  Probably you'll want to install allso signal handlers for `SIGQUIT` (`^]` interrupt key) and `SIGHUP` (end of session) in addition to `SIGTERM`.

From my point of view, if you are going to kill all the processes in a group, it is best to create a process group on the parent process (`setpgrp(0,0);`, see `setpgrp(2)`), then kill the process group (to `kill(2)` a process group you use the id of the group changed sign, `kill(SIGTERM, -getpgrp());`, (see the manpages for `kill(2)` and `setpgrp(2)`)